# How looks the "overarching" wavefunction of a number of electrons in an insulating sphere?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, entropy, potential-energy

I changed my question after reading the comment of Anna. If we put a huge number of electrons inside a non-conducting sphere, what will the total wavefunction describing all electrons look like?

I first assumed that the electrons could be treated as localized entities for which we could use the classical Coulomb force and in this context, I asked the following question:

The state with the highest entropy, which is the state of the electrons I ask for, seems to be the state where the electrons are uniformly distributed, but I'm not sure what influence the potential has. If they are uniformly distributed, you would think all the electrons move to the wall of the sphere, but on the other side, if they have (isotropically, as seen from the center of the sphere) accumulated near the wall, they repel each other with a greater force, which tend to drive them back to the aforementioned state. Will there be some intermediate state?

Now If we demand that the electrons should be treated quantum mechanically, the overarching statefunction, because of the potential between the (indistinguishable) electrons will surely affect the overarching wavefunction of the whole state. So I don't think this is a total wavefunction where all the electrons distribute themselves uniformly (each electron with a different momentum and two possible spins though). Doesn't this potential makes the total wavefunction lie somewhere between the two extreme cases where one of these represents the wavefunction where all electrons are uniformly distributed (though with different momenta, according to the exclusion principle) and the other where all electrons find themselves near the shell of the sphere?

Comment: electrons are elementary particles, i.e. quantum entities,and cannot be treated classically. See here for "electron gas" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas

Comment: So you can't see (in this case, where the number of electrons is small in comparison to the size of the sphere) the electrons as localized entities, as opposed to the electron quantum states, for example, in a two-dimensional box, where all of them are associated with a wavefunction "fitting" in the box and each electron state (although they are indistinguishable) is different as a consequence of the Exclusion Principle? Can't we treat the electrons as if they behave like classical particles (and their interaction is Coulomb-like)?

Comment: I do not think so, as the fact of their fermi nature, spin 1/2 cannot be ignored

Comment: Bre the electrons in this case far enough from each other so the wavefunctions (in the x-representation)  aren't influenced by spin up or down (if they are not entangled)?